# How to change the equation numbering in LaTex book document class?

Tags: equations, book-class

We know that the `book` class follows the structure below for numbering equations:

> Chapter 1
>
> First Equation (1.1)
>
> Second Equation (1.2)
>
> Chapter 2
>
> First Equation (2.1)
>
> Second Equation (2.2)
>
> Third Equation (2.3)

I want the `custom numbering format` described below:

> Chapter 1
>
> First Equation (1)
>
> Second Equation (2)
>
> Chapter 2
>
> First Equation (1)
>
> Second Equation (2)
>
> Third Equation (3)

As you can see the `chapter number` is not shown in the `equation` tag, but the equation numbers are reset as a new chapter is introduced. In addition, the equations are counted within each `chapter`.

Please tell me how to perform this action in `LaTeX`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is execute

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}
```

in the preamble.

A minimal working example (MWE):

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}   

\chapter{AAA}
\begin{equation} aaa \end{equation}
\begin{equation} bbb \end{equation}

\chapter{BBB}
\begin{equation} ccc \end{equation}
\begin{equation} ddd \end{equation}
\begin{equation} eee \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you don't need `\makeat...` or `\@addtoreset` here.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting and simplifying the relevant code.

Comment: Sir @Mico it's my pleasure....Legends like you have full rights to modify my suggestions...

Comment: We don't need `mathtools` package.  

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}} is sufficient.

Comment: @ArindamBandyopadhyay I've just added the package `mathtools` because of, if the `OP` want to use `amsmath` environments like `align`, `gather`, etc. nothing related with the equation numbers...